# Post Uploaded file to another PHP page?

Tags: php, http, file-upload, curl, https

Here is my problem.  I have a ticket-tracking system that is not very 'user friendly' but I have a desire for my users to submit 'tickets' to the system without having them to see it.

I got as far as just using a custom HTTP Form and posting to the ticket tracking system.  One problem is the 'success/completion' page has a tendency to confuse people.  So I figured... well since I cant change the ticket system to use a different 'success' page.  I will just handle the HTTP Post exchange with CURL and report a custom success or problem page.  Heres some abstracted code.

File: tickethelper.php

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
$url = 'TICKETSYSTEMURL';
$fields = array(
        'fullname'=>urlencode($fullname),
        /*many more fields*/
        );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$contents = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
if((strlen(strstr($contents,'Your ticket has been submitted')))>0){
        header("Location: http://THANKYOU");
}
        else{
                header("Location: http://OOPS");
        }

?>
```

However, what I realized is that I am missing my file upload.  Most of the CURL examples I have seen are to do with uploading local files to a remote HTTP POST page.

How do I handle receiving a file from my users HTTP form, process this in the 'tickethelper' and POST that to the 'TICKETSYSTEMURL' ?

-Israel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't say I've done this myself, but according to the PHP documentation regarding CURL and File Handling ([PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php))

> CURLOPT_INFILE | The file that the transfer should be read from when uploading.
>
> value should be a stream resource (using fopen(), for example) for the following values of the option parameter:

You should be able to call `fopen()` on the file that has been uploaded (refer to documentation regarding [Handling File Uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)) I'm not sure, but you may need to call `move_uploaded_file()` to a controlled directory on the server before calling `fopen()`

For example:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$file = fopen($_FILES['file-field-name']['tmp_name'], 'r');

// OTHER CURL CONFIGURATION
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);

curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your script can access the uploaded file through the $_FILES array.

From http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

> The $_FILES array is where PHP stores
>   all the information about files. There
>   are two elements of this array that we
>   will need to understand for this
>   example.
>
> - uploadedfile - uploadedfile is the reference we assigned in our HTML
>     form. We will need this to tell the
>     $_FILES array which file we want to
>     play around with.
> - $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] - name contains the original path of the user uploaded file.
> - $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] -
>     tmp_name contains the path to the
>     temporary file that resides on the
>     server. The file should exist on the
>     server in a temporary directory with a
>     temporary name.

To include this file in the POST you send with libcurl, use an array of fields instead of a string.  Include the file as one of the fields:

```
$post_fields = array (
    $key => $value,
    ...
    $file_key => "@" . $filename,
);
```

If you use the "@" symbol, libcurl will read the file and include it in the POST.

Then use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
```

Comment: Now my question is.  Do I loose the original name?  I did a print_r($_FILES) and I see the original name, and the temp path for the file.  When my other application posts the file will it be /tmp/kwsnWjwn instead of 'FriendlyName.xls' ?

Comment: Israel Lopez, you will lose the original name using libcurl. I do not believe you can set this value using libcurl, although other tools may allow it. However, you can use PHP's move_uploaded_file() function to move/rename the temp file to a friendly name on your system, and then use that file in your $post_fields array.